# UNLOAD: what are slices in the cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

According to the [AWS documentation for UNLOAD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) the number of files written to S3 are the "number of slices in the cluster". Our cluster has 24 nodes.

1. What counts as a slice? Why are we getting 64 files on S3 (see screenshot) and not 24?
2. Most files are around 37MB but some only ~300B (only contain the column headers), why are these files added?

[image: S3 extract]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of a slice as a partition on each node, by default each node will have at least 2 slices however this default does vary by the node size.

> A compute node is partitioned into slices. Each slice is allocated a portion of the node's memory and disk space, where it processes a portion of the workload assigned to the node. The leader node manages distributing data to the slices and apportions the workload for any queries or other database operations to the slices. The slices then work in parallel to complete the operation.

The files will vary in size depending on how the data is distributed across nodes (this is decided by your distribution keys). If you're getting some files with little data this would mean that the result set from your query is retrieving minimal data from one slive whilst gaining more from another slice.

If you haven't ever configured your distribution scheme in the schema of a table it will by default be `EVEN`.

The below links should help to go into further details on these subjects:

- [Data warehouse system architecture](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_high_level_system_architecture.html)
- [Amazon Redshift clusters - Node type details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-clusters.html#rs-node-type-info)
- [Distribution styles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_choosing_dist_sort.html)